# How to write nested query in mongodb using java

Tags: javascript, mongodb, database

I have to database in mongodb. One has documents like:

```
{name:"tom", locs:[{loc:"ca", type:0},{loc:"ny", type:1}]}
{name:"jack", locs:[{loc:"ca", type:0},{loc:"fl", type:2}]}
{name:"tina", locs:[{loc:"oh", type:3}]}
```

and the other:

```
{loc:"ca", area:163696, desc:"xxxx"}
{loc:"ny", area:54556, desc:"yyyy"}
{loc:"fl", area:65755, desc:"zzzz"}
{loc:"wa", area:71362, desc:"aaaa"}
```

I want to write query using java (mongo-java-driver) to find locs appears in the first database with specified "name"s and sort according to the "area" field in the second database. For names ['tom', 'jack'], get results like:

```
{loc:"ca", area:163696, desc:"xxxx"}
{loc:"fl", area:65755, desc:"zzzz"}
{loc:"ny", area:54556, desc:"yyyy"}
```

Because my database is really large, I cannot concatenate strings by two queries, first of which get all the locs from the first database and then concatenate them to ['ca', 'ny', 'fl'] and then use $in to do a join.

And also, I can do it with a javascript query in mongo client, which is:

```
db.y.find({'loc':{'$in':
    db.x.find({'name':{'$in':['tom', 'jack']}}).map(function(x){
        return x.locs.map(function(x){
            return x.loc;
        });
    }).reduce(function(x, y){
        return x.concat(y);
    })
}}).sort({'area':-1}).limit(50);
```

But as my database is sharded, I cannot use a db.runCommand("eval", query) to eval a javascript query for a sharded database. So how can i achieve this goal using mongo-java driver in java?